# Speed light power supply pinouts

Tags: flash, power-supply

I have a Nikon camera with a pair of Godox TT685N speed lights. I got the opportunity to get a couple of Nikon speed light battery packs for next to nothing. Godox uses Canon power ports for all their flashes. I hate throwing away perfectly good battery packs, but somehow I have to convert that male Nikon plug into a male Canon plug. But I don't have the pinout information and my Googling lead me to battery pack vendors. :)

So, I did find the Canon info: GND and +300V pins have an obstruction between them. I just need the Nikon info now, and then source a Canon plug.

Comment: What is the model number of the battery packs?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the Nikon connections are all (relatively) low voltage. There is no 300V output, which the Canon connection requires. To use the power supply, I'd have to manufacture a hole in the battery door and wire it up to the battery connections. I won't be doing that.

For future reference, just know that Godox uses Canon connections on all of their speed lights, so get a Canon style power pack if you want an auxiliary power pack.